# Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS Network problem

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, network-manager, gui

Ok everyone, I am "sorta" new to ubuntu and am now running a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.

I did a basic install of 12.04 lts 64-bit. After initial boot I logged in and ran 'sudo apt-get update'. After this i installed 'ubuntu-desktop' and 64-bit oracle jre. I have configured my static IP using the terminal. Everything was running great until I shutdown this morning to upgrade its RAM. The new ram is installed now and the server is running, but now network manager (ugh) is showing no wired connections. I have scoured the internet for a solution and have yet to find anything wrong with my settings.

I have the server KVM'd to my main desktop pc, and am writing this from that pc. Unfortunately, this makes it hard to copy paste from the server. I will provide any further information needed.

```
:~$ ifconfig
eth0
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:4d:d4:f5:77:4e  
      inet addr:10.1.10.100  Bcast:10.1.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::fe4d:d4ff:fef5:774e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:43114 (43.1 KB)  TX bytes:17701 (17.7 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000 

lo  Link encap:Local Loopback  
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:4640 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:4640 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
        RX bytes:371208 (371.2 KB) TX bytes:371208 (371.2 KB)
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
#This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.1.10.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.1.10.1
```

/etc/resolve.conf
is appearently empty now.. must have been reset by network manager...

/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManger.conf
is also empty... i opened this to change it to:

```
[ifupdown]
manual=true
```

since I read on ubuntu forums that I needed to do it in order to stop network manager from interfering with my manually configured terminal settings. I am not sure why it is an empty file...

One last thing for now, let me explain what I meant by "Everything was running great". I am running a minecraft server from this machine, it has been running and functioning properly until the shutdown today, and should continue to run after I fix this connection problem. By functioning properly I mean, This morning when i logged in to shut it down, my internet connection was still valid and working and i was still able to connect into the minecraft server from an external IP. I shutdown this morning, removed the RAM and doubled it, upon initial boot I am now stuck with this problem of no internet, yet every command I run appears to show the static is fine and I shouldn't have a problem. Thank you for your help and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether you are trying to use the **networking** service (configured via the /etc/network/interfaces file) or the **network-manager** service (configured via the GUI). Normally, a true server would use the former, and wouldn't even have a GUI.

You *probably* need to restore the original `lo` definition and add some `dns-nameservers` (I've used Google nameservers `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4` here - substitute your own choice(s) as appropriate).

```
 # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
 # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

 # The loopback network interface
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 # The primary network interface
 auto eth0
 iface lo inet loopback
     address 10.1.10.100
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 10.1.10.1
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8  8.8.4.4
```

If you're not actually using network-manager then it doesn't really matter what you put in it, however if you want it to show the status of the connection then I believe the appropriate `[ifupdown]` entry is

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

(not `manual=true`).

Comment: lol yea thats what I meant... "Managed". I apologize, it has been a really long week. Yes I did originally configure it manually using the network service. I have no intention of using the gui's network manager, I installed the gui because its easier for me to be able to view the web through a browser. I only included the network manager part because of what I read here about shutting it down to prevent conflict. http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu-the-proper-way/ I will go make the changes now, Thank you. @steeldriver

Comment: That fixed it. I was wondering after I discovered the resolve.conf was empty that my only issue might actually be that of the DNS not being there. I had read that it should be put into the /etc/network/interfaces file rather than resolve.conf. Anyways, I have accepted your Answer as the answer to this issue since after reconfiguring it the way you suggested I now have internet connectivity.